# gulp src ignore files from all folder but one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

This is my folder structure

```
views
|
- core
| |
|  -core.module.js
|   core.controller.js
|   some.js
|
- home
  |
  -home.module.js
   home.controller.js
   somemore.js
...
...
```

and in my gulp file I want to include all `js` files from `views` folder recursively and exclude `*.controller.js` from all folders but the `core`

i.e select all `js` files from `core` folder and select all but `*.controller.js` from all other folders

I tried like below, but its excluding `*.controller.js` files from `core` folder too.

```
gulp.src([
    //include all from all folders
    'views/**/*.js', 
    //exclude *.controller.js from all folders but core (not working)
    '!views/{**, !core}/*.controller.js'
])
```

Comment: Doesn't views/core/controller.js match that pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `!()` glob pattern. From the [`glob` documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer):

> `!(pattern|pattern|pattern)` Matches anything that does not match any of the patterns provided.

So in your case you can do the following:

```
gulp.src([
  'views/**/*.js', 
  '!views/!(core)/**/*.controller.js'
])
```

Comment: perfect.. Thanks, i thought `{folder}` and `(file)` so didnt try this way